# SSJS RegExp Are Broken?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, regular-expressions

The Regular Expressions in SSJS Email Studio seem to be broken or have different results than expected, Is anyone able to shed some light on this discrepancy and how I can work around this? Thank you.

**Javascript**

Regex: `[\w]+`

Input: `{variable1}-{variable2}-{variable3}-{variable4}-{variable5}`

Result: 5 Matches

**SSJS**

```
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
  Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");
  var str = "{variable1}-{variable2}-{variable3}-{variable4}-{variable5}";
  var re = new RegExp('[\\w]+', 'g'); 
  var match = re.exec(str);
  Variable.SetValue("@match", match.join(';'));
  Variable.SetValue("@Position", "Count:".concat(match.length));
</script>
```

**Output**:

```
Count:3
Match: variable1;;
```

**The Problem**: It only ever finds the first match; never additional matches or even groups. Makes it very difficult to do any form of validation when I can't pick out a `Match` or `Group`.

Comment: As far as I know, the RegEx in SFMC SSJS is broken.

Comment: And by broken I mean-- for this scenario the RegEx function doesn't work.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs thanks adam; any other way that you suggest I can do validation without hard-coding everything into a template?

Comment: I'd use a couple of replace() functions to get single delimiter characters and then buildRowSetFromString() in AMPscript or split in SSJS.